# MongoDB query performance with date

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a MongoDb collection containing docs with the following fields:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a3276fcc36bd0100504a95"), 
    "employeeId" : "5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4", 
    "isoDate" : ISODate("2016-01-31T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
{ isoDate: {
        $gte: new Date("2016-01-30T23:00:00.000+0000"),
        $lte: new Date("2016-01-31T23:00:00.000+0000")
      },
  employeeId: "5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4"
}
```

When having about 5000 entries in the collection, this query takes about 300ms in 8 Core / 8GB VM with SSD which seems to be pretty slow (the result contains about 3 to 6 docs).

Creating an index containing `employeeId` and `isoDate` doesn't seem to improve the performance.

The MongoDB version is 3.2.

*Update*
The output of `explain()` looks like this:

```
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "calendarentries",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "employeeId": {
            "$eq": "5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4"
          }
        },
        {
          "isoDate": {
            "$lte": {
              "$date": "2016-02-10T23:00:00.000+0000"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "isoDate": {
            "$gte": {
              "$date": "2016-01-30T23:00:00.000+0000"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "isoDate": 1,
          "employeeId": 1
        },
        "indexName": "calendarquery",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": 1,
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "isoDate": [
            "[new Date(1454194800000), new Date(1455145200000)]"
          ],
          "employeeId": [
            "[\"5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4\", \"5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4\"]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": []
  },
  "executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 18,
    "executionTimeMillis": 0,
    "totalKeysExamined": 37,
    "totalDocsExamined": 18,
    "executionStages": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "nReturned": 18,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
      "works": 37,
      "advanced": 18,
      "needTime": 18,
      "needYield": 0,
      "saveState": 0,
      "restoreState": 0,
      "isEOF": 1,
      "invalidates": 0,
      "docsExamined": 18,
      "alreadyHasObj": 0,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned": 18,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 37,
        "advanced": 18,
        "needTime": 18,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 0,
        "restoreState": 0,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "keyPattern": {
          "isoDate": 1,
          "employeeId": 1
        },
        "indexName": "calendarquery",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": 1,
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "isoDate": [
            "[new Date(1454194800000), new Date(1455145200000)]"
          ],
          "employeeId": [
            "[\"5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4\", \"5698f1a65d79d07f19ec0ee4\"]"
          ]
        },
        "keysExamined": 37,
        "dupsTested": 0,
        "dupsDropped": 0,
        "seenInvalidated": 0
      }
    },
    "allPlansExecution": []
  },
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "f9e2110ba93e",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "3.2.4",
    "gitVersion": "e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Could you get the output of explain() on your query and add it to the question?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Thanks for updating but this query doesn't seem to be taking 300ms. From what I can tell it's done under a millisecond ("executionTimeMillis": 0). Is this your slow query or is that a different one and/or on a different server?

Comment: Looks like most of the time has been caused by mongoose. I thought the results I got were plain MongoDB. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That would have been my guess. Good luck!